# Peltier Cooling

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, peltier, cooling

I am trying to incorporate a peltier module on a relatively small space. Is there a way to incorporate a 40 x 40 mm heat sink (+- 10mm) to a 40 x 40 mm peltier module in such a way that it can run for more than 10 mins running on 48 Watts whilst removing heat from the peltier module as to maintain a stable cooling temperature? The system also includes a 40 x 40 mm fan.

Are there other passive cooling methods (i.e. usage of coolant) appropriate to further dissipate the heat from the heat sink other than forced convection from a fan?

Comment: Have a look on the internet at projects using peltier elements. Note how the power into the peltier element is often much less than 60 W and how even that lower power requires **much** larger coolers than 40 x 40 mm. Look up the thermal resistance of a 40 x 40 mm heatsink and then do the calculation what the temperature would be if it needed to dissipate 60 W.

Comment: I've edited the question. The TEC that I use runs on 48 W. Are there ways other than the incorporation of massive heat sinks? I am very much limited in terms of spatial and weight margins.

Comment: *Are there ways other than the incorporation of massive heat sinks?* Yes, heat pipes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pipe to transport the heat somewhere else and then transfer it so the air there (again using a massive heatsink), or water cooling but that will require a large radiator as well. Think about it: lots of (heat) energy in a small space, what will happen? You simply want the impossible.

Comment: Well, I am thinking of incorportating additional mini DC fan. Is it appropriate?

Comment: Through my own failures with peltier coolers I would suggest that you only use them for non-constant heat loads (not continuously producing heat output). The problem stems from their inefficiency. You get a lot more heat out than you're removing from your main element you're trying to cool, so it can actually increase the difficulty of thermal management. I'd go the direct route of heat pipes if their thermal transfer meets your requirements. If you need below ambient cooling, on a non-constant load or a load that is very low in TDP, heat pipes with the peltier might work.